# configuring GWT devmode sources location

Tags: gwt, maven-2, multi-module

I've seen that changing a source java file that contains GWT code(i.e. creating buttons, labels), gets reloaded automatically when I hit browser refresh.

I'm doing a multi-module maven project with these modules:

- client
- shared
- server

but the GWT code reloading feature only works in a single-module project. Which config files tell GWT where to reload it's sources from? How do I configure this feature in a multi-module maven project?

Thanks

Comment: Can you be specific about the problem that you're having?

Comment: My setup is a bit complex to explain here, but basically I just need some tutorial or infos about how GWT reloads the code when I refresh the browser. Something like a under-the-hood GWT article/blog.

Comment: I just found http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/gwt-linkers-webworkers-extensions.html and I'm watching right now, but I'm not yet sure it contains what I look for

Comment: If your application is fully loaded in development mode then all appropriate code will be updated with a browser refresh. Note that server-side code may or may note be appropriately updated when modified - it depends on how you are deploying the server side code.

Comment: It's client code that doesn't get reloaded. When I have multi-maven modules(I've started from the hupa GWT app as base), if I change something in a .ui.xml file, it gets reloaded but if I change something in a .java file, it doesn't. If I knew how GWT works internally, I'd be able to debug this.

Comment: OK, which project are you running development mode from and which project contains the "unseen" changes?

Comment: I'm running the dev mode from project "client", and this project also contains the java sources in which I get unseen changes.

Comment: @Jason Terk: I managed to make it work - I just reopened Eclipse - even though it works, I can't understand how does GWT compile the sources at runtime and where does it store the compilation result

Comment: This may be helpful: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/DesignOOPHM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GWT loads files (java, ui.xml, css, etc.) from the classpath. How to configure DevMode to automatically reload your changes depends on how you run it: GPE or `mvn gwt:run`.